# Is the bulk_action hook stable for use in 3.2.X?

Tags: plugins, bulk

Working on a plugin for wp-ecommerce

publish / unpublish all items in a category

seems the cleanest place to implement this is in the categories page
as a bulk action - though numerous google searches have turned up very little documentation and a series of posts on bug tracker

so: Is it now safe to add a bulk_action-ID hook or should I make a custom sub-page in the admin?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Long story short the answer is NO

There is no function currently available to add bulk_actions

only remove them